# set the center as Europe at zoom level 1

Tags: google-maps

I try to get a certain set of coordinates to display. I get this done with the google maps API, but somehow the US ends up to be the center of the world. I tried

```
map.setCenter( latlngbounds.getCenter(), map.fitBounds( latlngbounds ) );
```

and

```
var dor24 = new google.maps.LatLng(52.519325,13.392709);
map.setCenter( dor24);
map.fitBounds( latlngbounds );
```

But somehow my setting the center is ignored when at zoom level 1. Is this due to inner workings of google maps or is there a way to get a world map centered on Europe and all points showing?

These are the exmples I am talking about:
http://hpsg.fu-berlin.de/~stefan/Vortraege/

http://hpsg.fu-berlin.de/~stefan/Vortraege/talk-map.html

*Edit:* But without fitbounds I get this:

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue and include it **in your question itself** not (only) links to external pages that exhibit the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Don't call both `map.setCenter` and `map.fitBounds`, `map.fitBounds` resets the map center.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/v5wcdyyr/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 1,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var dor24 = new google.maps.LatLng(52.519325, 13.392709);
  map.setCenter(dor24);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 256px;
  width: 256px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I edited the question. When I do not use fitBounds I get a huge map.

Comment: If this didn't address your question, please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue and include it **in your question itself** not (only) links to external pages that exhibit the problem (as requested previously).